# Get React variable in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these variables inside of a React component. How can I access the `bookings` variable in a vanilla JS file that I imported above?

```
import "./script.js" {/* I want to access the bookings variable in this file */}

const Booking = () => {
let [bookings, setBookings] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    getBookings()
}, [])

let getBookings = async () => {
    let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/all/bookings/")
    let data = await response.json()
    setBookings(data)
}
...
}
```

Comment: you'd have to call a function to say what the bookings are. you can't pass it to an import

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your bookings in a function. That way you can easy import them and get access through a simple call.

Comment: You have the right idea, but I don't understand how I would export the bookings in a function since hooks can only be used in components (sorry I'm new to React).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with a global variable since I couldn't figure out a better way.

React

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.globalvar = bookings;
}, [bookings])
```

JavaScript

```
let data = window.globalvar
```